# Linq query runs in a fraction of a second, but .ToList() takes 3.5 seconds

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I'm running a Linq query that returns about 25 records, each with 10 numeric columns.  According to my code profiler, the query itself is taking a fraction of a second - but the call to `.ToList()` is taking about 3.5 seconds.  As noted, the volume of data return from SQL is trivial, so the time taken to copy it into a `List` should not be burdensome.

Why is `.ToList()` taking so long?  And how could it be improved?

**EDIT:** With appreciation to all the rapid answers, let me state more clearly: I am completely aware of the fact that the query is lazy loaded.  The phenomenon I am seeing is that both SQL Server Profiler and ANTS Performance Profiler are reporting that the **actual query execution time** was a fraction of a second.

Here's a screen shot from ANTS:

[image]

Notice that the calling method is taking 4.3 seconds, while none of the actual SQL queries is taking longer than .05 seconds.  Could it be other code in that method, and not SQL?  Let's look at how ANTS breaks down the code profile here:

[image]

Smoking gun proof: `.ToList()` is taking 3.36 seconds, of which maybe 0.05 sec can be attributed to actual query execution time, leaving 3.31 sec unaccounted for.

Where's that time going to?

**EDIT 2:** Okay, you asked for it, so here's my code:

```
public static Expression<Func<Student, Chart>> GetStudentAssessmentQuestionResultByStudentIdNew(MyDataEntities db)
{
    return s => new Chart
        {
            studentID = s.ID,
            Lines =
                    db.StudentAssessmentAnswers
                        .Where(
                                saa =>
                                saa.StudentAssessment.BorrowedBook.StudentID == s.ID && saa.PointsAwarded != null &&
                                saa.Question.PointValue > 0 &&
                                (saa.Question.QuestionType == QuestionType.MultipleChoice ||
                                 saa.Question.QuestionType == QuestionType.OpenEnded))
                        .GroupBy(
                                saa =>
                                new
                                {
                                    saa.StudentAssessment.AssessmentYear,
                                    saa.StudentAssessment.AssessmentMonth,
                                    saa.Question.CommonCoreStandard
                                },
                                saa => saa)
                        .Select(x => new
                                     {
                                         x.Key.AssessmentYear,
                                         x.Key.AssessmentMonth,
                                         x.Key.CommonCoreStandard,
                                         PercentagePointValue =
                                         (float)(x.Sum(a => a.PointsAwarded) * 100) / (x.Sum(a => a.Question.PointValue))
                                     })
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.CommonCoreStandard)
                        .GroupBy(r1 => (byte)r1.CommonCoreStandard)
                        .Select(g => new ChartLine
                                     {
                                         ChartType = ((ChartType)g.Key),
                                         //type = g.Key.ToString(),
                                         type = g.Key,
                                         Points = g.Select(grp => new ChartPoint
                                                {
                                                    Year = grp.AssessmentYear.Value,
                                                    Month = grp.AssessmentMonth.Value,
                                                    yValue = grp.PercentagePointValue
                                                })
                                     })
        };
}
```

This is called by:

```
var students =
    db.ClassEnrollments
        .Where(ce => ce.SchoolClass.HomeRoomTeacherID == teacherID)
        .Select(s => s.Student);
var charts = CCProgressChart.GetStudentAssessmentQuestionResultByStudentIdNew(db);
var chartList = students.Select(charts).ToList();
```

Does that help any?

Comment: Maybe you have something like this `db.Select(r => somefields).ToList().Where(i => filterHere);`. Then your query would select all records and you would filter them in memory. Put the `Where` before the materialization, so before `ToList`.

Comment: What **is** your query?

Comment: A common subtlety of the point @Tim mentions is if you change the type to `IEnumerable<T>` too soon, rather than `IQueryable<T>` - for example: `IEnumerable<Person> people = db.People; var qry = people.Where(x => x.Id == 12345).ToList();` - this drags the entire table over the network and performs the `Where` in LINQ-to-Objects rather than via EF (which would do the filter at the database). So: can you show some code?

Comment: @Shaul unfortunately, for a more complex "missing time" problem, without the ability to reproduce it locally it is going to be very hard for anyone to answer that. Does your data-context already have a lot of data loaded into it, for example? What I *will* say is: we have experienced odd missing time when using ORMs, due to overheads inside the ORMs themselves. That was our reason for writing "dapper", which very deliberately *doesn't do* any of those things - but is just a very simple "query in, data out" layer.

Comment: @MarcGravell I got these results running off a single unit test.  Just to ensure the time wasn't going into the overhead of opening the SQL connection, I ran a trivial SQL query to count the records in some table before running this query.  If it's any help, I've updated the question with a snippet of my code.

Comment: that is a very complex query; have you snagged the raw SQL and executed it in SSMS or similar? (note: it might be more than one query, at that complexity)

Comment: @MarcGravell yes, and it also executes in SSMS in under a second.  (Can you get SSMS to display milliseconds?)

Comment: @Shaul tricky scenario to debug, I'm afraid

Comment: @MarcGravell - Humph.  Looks like ANTS is doing a Heisenberg on us.  I ran my unit test from a compiled exe, and the whole thing took 0.7 seconds.  Oh well... thanks anyway... :)

Answer (score 9):

`.ToList()` is actually **executing** the query. So your query is taking 2.5 seconds to run.

Read more about Deferred Execution [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738633.aspx).

Without posting your actual LINQ query, we have no means to help you with it's performance (if you post it, I'll update my answer).

Comment: @Shaul Can you post the offending LINQ? It looks like you might be returning a **lot** of rows (like some have said, perform `.ToList()` and **then** performing a `.Where()`).

Comment: Does it matter?  If the profiler tells me that the query is executing in .05 seconds, then it's not like the query needs to be optimized?

Comment: @Shaul TO be honest, I don't really trust the timings in ANTS to be **exactly** as stated. Without seeing any of your code, nobody will be able to help you further.

Comment: @Shaul Out of interest, if you call `.ToList()` after `.Select(s => s.Student)` does that affect the timing?

Comment: Well, it breaks compilation since `charts` is of type `Expression<Func<,>>`, so it won't work on a `List` type, only on an `IQueryable`.  I did try assigning `.ToList()` to a dummy variable, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Shaul What did I tell you? I don't trust ANTS timings :P

Answer (score 4):

LINQ to SQL is lazy loaded. Nothing actually happens until you call the ToList().

Edit:

Since you've updated your answer there's a few things to note.  ToList() is taking 73.4% of the time in the constructor.  This is the place the SQL statment is actually executed.  Below is the actual ToList method:

```
public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source != null)
    {
        return new List<TSource>(source);
    }
    else
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
}
```

Your SQL is not actually executed until the following line is called:

```
return new List<TSource>(source);
```

So yes ToList is taking forever but that's because its started to process the source parameter.  Antz is a very useful tool but it can sometimes lead your down the wrong path.  The issue is most likely going to be one of these:

1. The T-SQL generated is hideous and slow.
2. Opening the connection to the SQL server is slow
3. Your lambda expression tree is complicated and entity framework is taking a long time to process it and generate the T-SQL

I would start by first opening up SQL profiler and looking at the SQL.  Even what looks like the simplest statement can be doing something crazy, the only way to know for sure is to look at the actual T-SQL.

If the T-SQL is ok your going to have to play around with your Lambda expression to make it simpler, and easier to process.

Comment: Thank you.  As it turns out, ANTS was doing a Heisenberg on me... see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16813999/7850)

Answer (score 3):

Linq2SQL uses something called Lazy Loading. Basically until you look in the container you asked for, it doesn't go near the data source. You can keep building up your query, but as soon as you toList it, or look at the First, it builds up your query, sends it to the database and waits for the result.... hence it takes so long

Answer (score 2):

Without more detail, it's hard to know for sure. But, what type is your `List` of? What does that class do in the constructor/setters? Does it implement INotifyPropertyChanged, or fire any other events?

Bear in mind the query will only be executed when you call `ToList`. Up until that point, it's just a queryable object. Look at it with a SQL profiler, and you'll see that *that's* when it does the DB access.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after all that, it turns out that ANTS was doing a Heisenberg on us.

The way things played out was that I originally got a complaint about poor performance in this area.  I ran ANTS and identified that this code was responsible.  So I refactored, optimized and the result was the code you see in the question.  I then retested, and found a significant improvement, but performance was still unacceptable.  Then came the SO question.

And then I decided to try running the unit test without ANTS... and it ran in a fraction of a second.

Lesson learned: sometimes the performance profiler is itself the reason for poor performance.